# How to sort a populated document in find request?

Tags: mongoose

I would like to sort a populated Document from the collection i fetch, i get an error requesting it.

Let's admit a Document `Group` (Group) and 'Member' (Group.Members)

```
Group
  .find({})
  .populate('Members')
```

Works perfectly, but i would like to sort it so i do this:

```
Group
  .find({})
  .populate('Members', ['_id', 'name'], null, { sort: [[ 'created_at', 'desc' ]] })
```

I get the error `TypeError: Invalid select() argument. Must be a string or object.` by adding this...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This example above works with Mongoose 2.x and above, use this syntax:

```
Group
  .find({})
  .populate('Members', '_id name', null, { sort: { 'created_at': -1 } })
```

Comment: May i know what does the  ~'_id name', null,~ stands here?

Comment: @KannanT , This stands for just select _id and name field from mebers collection

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me. 
what worked for me is something like 
.populate({ path:'Members',
select : 'name',
options : { sort: created_at : -1 } })

Answer (score 83):

You can also explicitly specify only required parameters of populate:

```
Group
  .find({})
  .populate({path: 'Members', options: { sort: { 'created_at': -1 } } })
```

Have a look at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate

Comment: Thanks, Artem. It really solved my problem, but I am still unable to find a resource which digs deep into how Sorting with Mongoose really works!

Answer (score 18):

And for Mongoose 4.x use this syntax:

```
Kitten.find().populate({
    path: 'owner'
  , select: 'name'
  , match: { color: 'black' }
  , options: { sort: { name: -1 }}
}).exec(function (err, kittens) {
  console.log(kittens[0].owner.name) // Zoopa
})

// alternatively
Kitten.find().populate('owner', 'name', null, {sort: { name: -1 }}).exec(function (err, kittens) {
  console.log(kittens[0].owner.name) // Zoopa
})
```

Reference: [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate)

Comment: Also, I can not find exact reference of the behavior of the sort option in mongoose. 

But for sure options is the 5th parameter in the alternative syntax, after path, select, model and match.

Comment: @NicoPasserini sorry if it does not work for you, it is the exact example from the official documentation that is linked in the answer. So you probably doing sth wrong.

Comment: I think it is a confirmed bug, please take a look at: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2202.

Comment: I am using mongoose 4.6 and my code looks like this 
`        .populate({
         path: 'bookedFor.id',
         select: 'name mobileNumber',
         options: {
          sort: { mobileNumber: -1 }
         }
        })` 
But it is not working, Can anyone point out the error?

Answer (score 8):

This worked correctly for me in Mongoose Versions 5 and above.

```
Clinics.findById(req.params.id).populate({path:'users',options:{ sort:{date : 1}}}).exec(callback);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I wonder, is there any documentation where they mention populate options? What I mean is that in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions some path, select, perDocumentLimit, match, name and options are mentioned. Are there other options besides these? It's all very little detailed. For example, they only mention options for limit, but they don't even explain options, where did you get that sort could be included in options?

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me in Mongoose v5.0.5:

```html
    Schedule.find({})
        .populate({path: 'eventComments', options: {sort:{"commentDate": "descending"}}})
        .exec(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err
            } 

            else {
                return res.json(result);
            }
    });
```

P.S. The key difference between this example and the Kitten example is that *commentDate* is in quotes, whereas *Date* (in the Kitten example) is not.  This alteration may be necessary for some of you.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This really worked for me:

```
User.find({}).populate({path: 'photos', options: { sort: { 'CreatedAt': -1 } } })
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing to populate a nested document, this worked for me:

```
const video = await Video.findOne({ urlId }) // find video
        .populate('likes user') // populate the likes and owner (user) of video
        .populate({
            path: 'comments', // populate the comments as well,
            options: { sort: { date: -1 } }, // sorting the comments by date
            populate: {
                path: 'user', // and populating the owner (user) of each comment,
                select: 'username, date', // plucking whichever fields necessary from the User model
            },
        })
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Comment.find({}).populate({path: 'comments', options: { sort: '-createdAt'} });`

-createdAt -> here - is for descending order