# mongo Nodejs populate sub document sort order

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch all documents in ASC(ascending) order. My data is

```
[{
  _id:xxxxxxx,
  bookdetails:{
    bookCost:{
     price:500,
     discount:10,
     createdAt:'2017-05-11',
    },
    name: yyyyyy,
   }
},{
  _id:xxxxxxx,
  bookdetails:{
    bookCost:{
     price:600,
     discount:10,
     createdAt:'2017-02-11',
    },
    name: yyyyyy,
   }
}]
```

Here is my code

```
db.Book.find({ bookId:id}, ('_id bookdetails'))
        .populate({
            path: 'bookdetails'
          })
        .sort({ 'bookCost.createdAt': 1 })
        .exec(function (err, docs) {
            if (!err) {
                let response =;
                callback(response);
            } else {
                callback({})
            }
        })
```

I want to display books based on Date created? Can you please correct me.

Comment: My code giving all books records without sort by createdAt

Comment: Possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352768/how-to-sort-a-populated-document-in-find-request

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Book.find({ bookId:id}, ('_id bookdetails'))
    .populate({
        path: 'bookdetails'
      })
    .sort({ 'bookdetails.bookCost.createdAt': 1 })
    .exec(function (err, docs) {
        if (!err) {
            let response =;
            callback(response);
        } else {
            callback({})
        }
    })
```