# How to sort Array of subdocument of a populated result in Nodejs using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose-populate

I want to retrieve article submmited by member in recent order based on time. Member Schema having array of _id of submitted article.
Below are the Schema of Member and Article -

**Member Schama**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
        const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
        const MemberSchema = new Schema({
            uid:{
                type:String,
                required:[true,'Must Required']
            },
            name:{
                type:String,
                default:[true,'Anonymous']
            },
            email:{
                type:String,
                required:[true,'Email Must Required']
            },

            profileimg:{
                type:String ,
                required:[true,'Profile Image Must Required']
            },
            notes:{
                type:String,
                default:[true,'Write your Notes Here']
            },
            country:{
                type:String,
                default:[true,'America']
            },
            profession:{
                type:String,
                default:[true,'Developer']
            },
            experience:{
                type:String,
                default:[true,'5']
            },
            article:[{_id:{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref : 'Article'}}]



        });

        const Member = mongoose.model('member',MemberSchema);

        module.exports = Member;
```

**Article Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ContentCardSchema = new Schema({
    cardtitle : String,
    cardbody : {
        type:String
    }
});
const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    author:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'member' ,
        required:[true,'UID Must Required']
    },
    status:{
        type:String,
        default:'PENDING'
    },
    category:{
        type:String,
        default:'Other'
    },
    title:{
        type:String,
        default:'Anonymous'
    },
    body:[ContentCardSchema],
    thumbimg:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Thumb Image Must Required']
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default:Date.now
    }



});

const Article = mongoose.model('Article',ArticleSchema);

module.exports = Article;
```

Time is stored in Article Schema not in the array of Member Schema. I want to get output in recent article first.

Below is Mongoose Populate Operation with sort but not working.

```
//Get Article Submitted by their Author using uid
router.get('/author/:uid',(req,res,next)=>{
    Member.findOne({uid:req.params.uid},'article').populate('article._id','title category thumbimg')
    .exec()
    .then((result)=>{
        res.status(200).json(result);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.send(404).json({error:err});
    })
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a populated document in find request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352768/how-to-sort-a-populated-document-in-find-request)

Comment: Have you tried the below answer?

Answer (score -1):

```js
//Get Article Submitted by their Author using uid
router.get('/author/:uid',(req,res,next)=>{
    Member.findOne({uid:req.params.uid},'article')
    .populate({path:'article._id',select: 'title category thumbimg', options: {sort : {yourfieldname :1}})
    .exec()
    .then((result)=>{
        res.status(200).json(result);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.send(404).json({error:err});
    })
});
```

Try above.Hope this  helps.