# Mongoose (Mongodb) sorting by populated field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've got a `Product` model, and each product has a `category` field. This category field get's populated, by mongoose, with the fields from the matching document in the `Category` collection. I am doing this in hopes to sort my product query by `category.popularity` which is just a simple number. The goal here is when you sort by popular, the query is ranked with the highest number first. I've been searching all night and implementing different ways of using sort but i'm either misunderstanding how it works or just not doing it right. Here is my call to get the products

```
const docs = await models.products
      .find(find, null, opts)
      .populate('retailer')
      .populate({
        path : 'category',
        select : 'popularity',
        options : { sort : { popularity : -1 } }
      })
```

This populates the field correctly, but does not sort it. Is this the correct way I would sort my products by their categories popularity? I've love to hear what you have to say, and if you need any more info, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: do you want to sort your result on the bases `popularity`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a populated document in find request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352768/how-to-sort-a-populated-document-in-find-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populate does not help to sort the ROOT/parent collection and also not a better option to perform join on two collections.

You have to use some alternative like [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get the sorted documents with with respect to child collection.

```
const docs = await models.products.aggregate([
  { "$match": { find }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Retailer.collection.name,
    "localField": "retailer",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "retailer"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Category.collection.name,
    "localField": "category",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "category"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$category" },
  { "$sort": { "category.popularity": 1 }}
])
```

Comment: wow im going to have to read some documentation! But this works exactly as I wanted man. The `find` variable is throwing an error becuase it has `$or : [
        { expires_at : { $gt : moment().toISOString() } },
        { expires_at : null }
      ],` but there is probably just a different way to do that in aggrigate

Comment: It works. But can't we sort it Case-insensitive?